# JQuery: multiple JSON requests with deferred/promise failed

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-deferred

we have an application to allow users to load data through Ajax requests. Say, we have a list of items called 'tracks'. Whenever the user click a track, we issue an Ajax request, get data and show. Each track is wrapped as a JQuery widget. The code to issue a request and handle the results are:

```
function _fullRefresh() {
    // Prepare parameters ...
    return $.Deferred(function(def) {
        $.getJSON(url, params, function(data) {
            callFunctionRunforLongTime(data);
                    // update some local variables.
            def.resolve();
        }).error(function() {
            def.reject();
        });
    }).promise();
}

......
loadingIcon.show();
this._fullRefresh(forced)
    .always(function() {
        loadingIcon.hide();
    }).fail(function() {
        showError();
    });
```

The problem happens when we have multiple open tracks. Sometimes the user clicks a button 'zoom in', then EVERY open tracks will send a new request and update the data. Now wired things happens: sometimes the `promise` object is `rejected` (so error message is shown), but from the backend server side, the HTTP response code is `200`, which means the backend sends the data without error.

**The error doesn't always happen when the user clicks too fast. It possibly occurs when the user clicks the button once.**

Meanwhile, the code to update local widget variables sometimes fails. In my implementation, the code to update the local widget variables is around 10 lines.

What is the reason? Please help, thanks.

---

SOLVED.

Thanks to @charlietfl and @Beetroot-Beetroot. I found that the problem is not caused by the javascript. It is because that simultaneous queries to MySQL make the connection failed.

Comment: does `callFunctionRunforLongTime(data)` do anything asynchronous?

Comment: `$.getJSON` returns a decorated deferred object. You can call `promise()` directly on that to return a promise: `return $.getJSON(url, params, callFunctionRunforLongTime).promise()`. No need to manually construct a new `deferred` yourself.

Comment: @charlietfl No. `callFunctionRunforLongTime(data)` uses the Ajax data and cookie data to plot a canvas.

Comment: might also add some throttling on requests for when they hit button repeatedly

Comment: @JosephSilber Thanks. But I think your modification doesn't change the working flow. I would expect the same thing happening again.

Comment: @charlietfl The error could happen when there is only one click...

Comment: keep in mind that 200 status  doesn't mean you have data in response, or that data is in format expected...have you inspected requests in network tab of console, and looked at actual response body? For example if server outputs html error message when you expect json

Comment: Code in the question looks ok, though it could be written more simply (see Joseph Silber's comment). The bug(s) must be in the code that attaches event handler(s) and/or the data returned by `$.getJSON()` and/or `callFunctionRunforLongTime()`.

Comment: @meagar - The docs you linked to clearly state that it returns a `jqHXR` object, which like I said is a decorated deferred object.

Comment: @JosephSilber Ah, didn't realize it was `jqXHR` specifically that provided a promise interface for jQuery's AJAX functions. Never mind.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. Yeah, the response body states error, even though the response code is 200...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @charlietfl and @Beetroot-Beetroot. I found that the problem is not caused by the javascript. It is because that simultaneous queries to MySQL make the connection failed.